# Form (htm & ajax) not registering

Tags: php, ajax, html, forms

My AJAX code is refusing the post what is being filled into an html form. Rather than the actual contents, **my txt file is just filling up with the words 'firstname lastname age'**. Where am I going wrong?

(I have a submit button that, when pressed, will hide the div and open another one - don't know if this is important information)

This is the HTML:

```
General intro
            <form action="action_page.php">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal information:</legend>
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname">
            <br>
            Age (in numbers; e.g., "47", not "forty-seven"):<br>
            <input type="text" name="age">
            <br><br>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
            <p><button type=button id='Submit0'>Submit my information</button></p>
```

This is the code in my action_page.php

```
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];

$out;

$result = file_put_contents("log.txt", PHP_EOL ."firstname" . $firstname . " lastname " . $lastname ."age" . $age, FILE_APPEND);


if ($result !== FALSE) {
  $out = [ "message" => "success!", "status" => 200];
}
else {
  $out = [ "message" => "error saving file", "status" => 500];
}


echo json_encode($out);
    exit();
```

Comment: Where is the AJAX code? maybe you jist have to put method="POST" to your form: <form action="action_page.php" method="POST">

Comment: Does the form hit `action_page.php`? `die("here i am");` at the top of the page to check.

Comment: it's a good method to add a quote ( ' ) or double quote(") in each attribute (just in case). Also, try adding the button inside the form and instead of `<button>` add a `<input type="submit">`, try first option first just in case it works. Also, add `method` onto the form tag

Comment: Show the code for the submit button.

Comment: method post does not work unfortunately, neither does putting the button inside the form, or adding an input type submit..

Comment: If I use the <input type = "submit"> I go to a page that says 'undefined index' at firstname, lastname,a ge..

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look like an Ajax to me,
but you should be able to solve your issue by changing

```
<form action="action_page.php">
```

to

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to make a difference.. and my apologies, I meant php rather than ajax

Comment: on your action_page.php try putting a `print_r($_REQUEST);` and a `print_r($_POST);` and see what is being sent from the form, does it have data in the expected fields? Also, just noticed, but try putting your submit button inside the form too...

Comment: Hi Dave. those commands don't do much.. I am open to a complete new approach, I just need people to fill in their name and age before they go to the website.. that's it. should've been one of the easier parts :)

Comment: @ShariDB like Cheshire said above, the input `<type="submit" ...>` (preferably inside the form) is important, since you're not submitting the actual form, the reason your getting the index not found is probably because you need the `method=post` to set the `$_POST` superglobal up with the form data stuff. So try  `method="POST"` add the submit button and try the `print_r`'s to see exactly if anything is being passed. If you did the `print_r`'s like I mentioned earlier and got nothing, then your  form isn't passing data to the action script.